# Callback never gets executed in Unity Web Player

Tags: c#, callback, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to post to my web api and use a callback when the post finishes. This all works perfectly in the Unity editor and as a Desktop app, but does NOT work in the Web Player. I have narrowed it down to just the callback not actually getting called. How can I use callbacks? Here is my code:

```
void ui_login() { 
if (uiBase == null) 
     return; 

Debug.LogError(uiBase); clicks++; status = "(" + clicks + ")" + "working";

var username = uiBase.UIElements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "txt_username");
var password = uiBase.UIElements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "txt_password");
try
{
    var request = new LoginRequest()
    {
        Email = username.Text,
        Password = password.Text
    };
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest<LoginResponse>(request, loginCallback));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    status = "(" + clicks + ")" + e;
}
}

void loginCallback(LoginResponse response, WWW www)
{
if (www.error != null)
    status = www.error;
if (response != null)
    status = response.ErrorMessage;
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequest<TResponse>(
LoginRequest request, Action<TResponse, WWW> callback)
{
var json = JsonMapper.ToJson(request);
var www = new WWW("http://someurl.com", json.ToBytes());
yield return www;
TResponse response;
if (www.error == null && www.isDone)
{
    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.bytes);
    print(str);
    status = str;
    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(str);
}

else
    response = default(TResponse);

print("somthif");
callback(response, www);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Unity Web Player works in a Sandbox and will block your HTTP requests.

To fix this issue, follow the process described in this link: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html